# how to put a loader until the images are not loaded

Tags: jquery, html, loader

My images are loaded from database through JSON so it takes time to load.
What I want is to put a loader which will remove when loading of image is finished.

This code is working but not properly if some one keeps clicking next or previous then it works fine, but if a user clicks next then previous or randomly it didn't remove the loader image.
Strange behavior is that image change is not affected by this only loader is not getting removed.
Given below is my HTML structure and JavaScript:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="815" align="center">
            <tr>
              <td><div class="btnPrv2" id="btnPrv2">&lt;</div></td>           
              <td><div class="slider">
                    <div class="mc3" id="mc3" ><img src="" class="ff3" /><img src="" class="fs3 loader" /></div>
                    <div class="mc4" id="mc4" ><img src="" class="ff4" /><img src="" class="fs4 loader" /></div>
                  </div>
              </td>           
              <td><div class="btnNxt2" id="btnNxt2">&gt;</div></td>           
            </tr>
          </table>


  <script>

          var npos=wpos=0,curwdiv = 3, totppl = relghm.length,canAnim = true,pos=0,cdiv=3, mcount=0;

         $(document).on("click","#btnNxt2",function(){

                if(wpos === totppl-1){  wpos = -1;}
                curP=0;
                if (wpos < totppl-1 && canAnim) {
                    wpos++; canAnim = false;
                    pos = wpos;

                    var hdiv = (curwdiv === 3) ? 4 : 3; 
                    $(".fs" + hdiv).attr("src","img/loader.gif");
                    $(".fs" + hdiv).css("display","block");

                    $(".ff" + hdiv).attr("src","./img/cms/" + relghm[wpos].image);
                    $(".ff" + hdiv).attr("alt", relghm[wpos].title);
                    $(".ff" + hdiv).attr("width", "782px");
                    $(".ff" + hdiv).attr("height", "441px");
                    $(".ff" + hdiv).attr("title", relghm[wpos].title);


                    $(".ff" + hdiv).load(function(){
                     console.log("image loaded");
                     $(".ff" + hdiv).css("display","block");
                     $(".fs" + hdiv).fadeOut(1000);

                    });


                    $(".mc" + hdiv).css({"left":782});

                    $(function(){
                      $(".mc3").animate({left:"-=782px" },450);
                      $(".mc4").animate({left:"-=782px" },450, function(){ curwdiv = hdiv; canAnim = true; });
                    });

                    cdiv = hdiv;


                    //if (wpos === totppl-1) { $("#btnNxt2").removeClass("btnNxt2").addClass("btnNxtG");  }


                }
                 curP=0;
            });

          $(document).on("click","#btnPrv2",function(){

                curP=0;
                if( wpos === 0){wpos = totppl}
                if (wpos >= 0 && canAnim ) {
                    wpos--; canAnim = false;
                    pos = wpos;

                    var hdiv = (curwdiv === 3) ? 4 : 3; 

                    $(".fs" + hdiv).attr("src","img/loader.gif");
                    $(".fs" + hdiv).css("display","block");


                    $(".ff" + hdiv).attr("src","./img/cms/" + relghm[wpos].image);
                    $(".ff" + hdiv).attr("alt", relghm[wpos].title);
                    $(".ff" + hdiv).attr("title", relghm[wpos].title);
                    $(".ff" + hdiv).attr("width", "782px");
                    $(".ff" + hdiv).attr("height", "441px");

                    $(".ff" + hdiv).load(function(){
                      $(".ff" + hdiv).css("display","block");
                      $(".fs" + hdiv).fadeOut(1000);

                    });

                    $(".mc" + hdiv).css({"left":-782});

                    $(function(){

                      $(".mc3").animate({left:"+=782px" },450, function(){});
                      $(".mc4").animate({left:"+=782px" },450, function(){ curwdiv = hdiv; canAnim = true; });
                    });

                    cdiv = hdiv;

                    //if (wpos === 0){ $("#btnPrv2").removeClass("btnPrv2").addClass("btnNxtG"); }

                }
                 curP=0;
            });

          var updCont = function(p,c) {
         // console.log("isset"+p);
          //console.log("div"+c);

            $(".fs" + c).attr("src","./img/loader.gif");
            $(".fs" + c).css("display","block");
            $(".ff" + c).attr("src","./img/cms/" + relghm[p].image);
            $(".ff" + c).attr("title",relghm[p].title);
            $(".ff" + c).attr("alt",relghm[p].title);
            wpos = p;

            $(".ff" + c).load(function(){

                     $(".ff" + c).css("display","block");
                     $(".fs" + c).fadeOut(1000);

                    });

      }
```

Comment: I don't think you will get help, If you don't organize your code, try to inspect the problem before asking about it!

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but after a long study on my code i am unable to find out why this error occurs

Answer (score 0):

Put this before action

```
$('#div').html('<img src="loader.png">');
```

Comment: Below this  $(document).on("click","#btnNxt2",function(){  you can put loader

Answer (score 0):

How about this - http://jsfiddle.net/4WhQc/

Html

```
<img id="test" src="loading.gif" />
```

setting all your img tag src with a loader gif and when you have your image from the db you can update the src. Till then the loader would be shown.